# What values of alpha guarantee the convergence of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left( \frac {\alpha n} {n+1}\right) ^{n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have managed to use the root test and get as far as getting the limit to equal to $1$. But, I still need clarification on why the answer for the limit to this questions is $\alpha < 1$.

\begin{align}
\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left( \frac {\alpha n} {n+1}\right) ^{n}\end{align}

\begin{align}
\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \left( \frac {\alpha n} {n+1}\right) ^{n}\right) ^{1/n}
=\left| \frac {\alpha n} {n+1}\right| =\alpha \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\left| \frac {n} {n+1}\right|=1.\end{align}

Comment: It might help you to look carefully at the statement of the root test.  Your question would be improved by including that statement in the body of the question, as this would help answerers to know what you are thinking, and what theory you know.

Comment: There is also an issue of the domain of this problem.  Where does $\alpha$ live?  Can is it real?  complex?  This does make a difference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \alpha^n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha^n\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e}\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha^n$$ the only way for this to converge to zero is that $|\alpha|<1$. Otherwise the sum will diverge. You can use this idea to check the series, for example: if $\alpha\geq 0$, then since $$\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\leq 1,\ \forall n $$ then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha^n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha^n<\infty\  \mathrm{iff} \ \alpha<1$$ notice as well that for $\alpha=1$ your series it's
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n=\infty $$ and the reason behind it is the limit previously computed.